# Loading external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I have a cross platform app built using PhoneGap/Cordova.

I am trying to implement a function that runs an external JavaScript file when a controller loads. I am following a solution from [**HERE**](http://haruair.com/externaljavascriptfile.js). And similarly [**HERE**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/HP-8wQS-FgM). But I want the JavaScript to execute without the window.open event, i.e. I want to run ***executeScript*** as soon as the device is ready.

How do I call the ***executeScript()*** without defining the ***var ref*** first though?

```
var navigation = angular.module("navigation", []);
navigation.controller("Navigation", function ($scope) {

    var init = function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    };

    init();

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // LOAD EXTERNAL SCRIPT
        var ref = window.open('http://www.haruair.com/', '_blank', 'location=yes, toolbar=yes, EnableViewPortScale=yes');
        ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function () {
            ref.executeScript(
              { file: 'http://haruair.com/externaljavascriptfile.js' },
              function () {
                  ref.executeScript(
                    { code: 'getSomething()' },
                    function (values) {
                        var data = values[0];
                        alert("Name: " + data.name + "\nAge: "  + data.age);
                    });
              }
            );
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add the script in the `index.html` file and do whatever you want from JS. Also, you must add to your whitelist this endpoint.

```
<!-- index.html -->

<script>
  function onCustomLoad() {
    //do stuff
  }
</script>
<script src="your-custom-script" onload="onCustomLoad"></script>
```

Comment: Yip. Added to both, but how do I actually call the method automatically from the onDeviceReady function? Im not sure on the syntax.

Comment: You could add to the script a `onload` listener to check when is loaded and another one to check when cordova is ready (trigger an event `cordovaReady` or someone similar)

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.id = "some_id";
script.src = 'http://haruair.com/externaljavascriptfile.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

then call the function once finished